# Dashes out the brackets of a matrix

Tags: matrices, arydshln, nicematrix

Using `nicematrix` for an answer I have seen that the dashes go out the matrix: you can see the first example. If I put `\,` before `\right[` and after `\left[` the dashes are into the matrix (second example).

What is the reason and if there is a solution in the manual that I have not read?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\textit{First example}:

\[\left[\begin{NiceArray}{c:c:c}
A & B & C  \\
\hdashline
D & E & F \\
\hdashline
G & H & O
\end{NiceArray}\right]
\]

\textit{Second example}:
\[\left[\,\begin{NiceArray}{c:c:c}
A & B & C  \\
\hdashline
D & E & F \\
\hdashline
G & H & O
\end{NiceArray}\,\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*ADDENDUM*: **Important** comment in the guide of the author of the package *F. Pantigny* July 15, 2020: In this version 5.0 of [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf), one must use the letters `l`, `c` and r in the preambles of the environments and no longer the letters `L`, C and `R`. For sake of compatibility with the previous versions, there exists an option define-`L-C-R` which must be used when loading `nicematrix`.

[image]

Comment: I get a compile error regarding theuse of lowercase `c` and requires me to use an uppercase 'C' for the column specification. Also, did you run it mroe than once?

Comment: I get fatal errors from your code.

Comment: @PeterGrill Good morning to you and thank you very much for your reply, I have put the screenshots of Papeeria TeXlive 2019, in chat, where I compile with another pc where I have not installed MikTeX 2.9. I don't get any compilation errors. Do you prefer that have I improved my code with `C` instead of `c`? Best regards.

Comment: @egreg I have added a message for you into chat. If you prefer you can try using Papeeria. Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano I know nothing about Papeeria. Quite likely they're using an outdated TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg Now, I change c with C. Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: With `C`, I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2018, but not with a later TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your feedback. I have set Papeeria with TeXlive 2019.

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). Untill now, `C` should be used instead of `c` in all situations in `nicematrix` (but, in a few days, I will upload on CTAN a new version using the standard letters `c`, `l` and `r`). Moreover, the most recent versions of `nicematrix` were using the most recent versions of `expl3`. Therefore, they may exist problems with TeXLive 2018 and even TeXive 2019. However, I think that the next version of `nicematrix`  will be more compatible (I will postpone the use of the most recent macros defined in `expl3`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny Yeah, I know, that's because I have written to you. . I have understood all your comment. I will also wait in the future how to remove dashes out of the matrix. My cordial greetings.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Hi, I have read your recent documentation but I have not found nothing to solve my problem. Probably I have read not very well. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile in Papeeria with the option TeXLive 2019, you use in fact the version 2.1.4 of `nicematrix` and you have indeed the output shown in your question. However, if you upload the latest version of  `nicematrix.sty` in Papeeria in your project (version 5.0), you will be able to use the latest version of `nicematrix`. I have tried and I have obtained the expected result.

[image: Ouput of above picture]